# Add taxonomy to already registered custom post type

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I want to add taxonomy to already registered custom post type. Is it possible or I have to delete and create that custom post type again??

```
 add_action('init', 'create_requirement');

function create_requirement() {
 register_post_type('requirement', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name'                  => __('Requirements','wpestate'),
        'singular_name'         => __('Requirement','wpestate'),
        'add_new'               => __('Add New Requirement','wpestate'),
        'add_new_item'          => __('Add Requirement','wpestate'),
        'edit'                  => __('Edit','wpestate'),
        'edit_item'             => __('Edit Requirement','wpestate'),
        'new_item'              => __('New Requirement','wpestate'),
        'view'                  => __('View','wpestate'),
        'view_item'             => __('View Requirement','wpestate'),
        'search_items'          => __('Search Requirement','wpestate'),
        'not_found'             => __('No Requirements found','wpestate'),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __('No Requirements found in Trash','wpestate'),
        'parent'                => __('Parent Property','wpestate')
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'requirements'),
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments','tags'),
    'can_export' => true,
    'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_property_metaboxes',
    'menu_icon'=>get_template_directory_uri().'/images/properties.png'
     )
   );


register_taxonomy('post_tag', 'estate_requirement', array(
'labels' => array(
    'name'              => __('Tags','wpestate'),
    'add_new_item'      => __('Add New Requirement Tag','wpestate'),
    'new_item_name'     => __('New Requirement Tag','wpestate')
  ),
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'query_var' => true,
   'rewrite' => true
  )
 );


 // add custom taxonomy
 register_taxonomy('req_category', 'estate_requirement', array(
 'labels' => array(
    'name'              => __('Requirement Categories','wpestate'),
    'add_new_item'      => __('Add New Requirement Category','wpestate'),
    'new_item_name'     => __('New Requirement Category','wpestate')
 ),
  'hierarchical' => true,
 'query_var' => true,
 'rewrite' => true
 )
 );


// add custom taxonomy
register_taxonomy('req_action_category', 'estate_requirement', array(
'labels' => array(
    'name'              => __('Requirement Action','wpestate'),
    'add_new_item'      => __('Add New Requirement Action','wpestate'),
    'new_item_name'     => __('New Requirement Action','wpestate')
),
'hierarchical' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => true
)

) ;
}
```

I have added req_category and req_action_category but it's not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here. First, you cannot create a taxonomy `post_tag`. `post_tag` is a reserved name and is actually used for the build in taxonomy `post_tag`. Secondly, your custom post type is called `requirement`, yet you add your taxonomies to a post type called `estate_requirement`.

If you fix that two problems, you should be fine

Comment: It solved my problem..actually I m new to wordpress so I dnt know the basics of wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the taxonomy without having to delete and recreate the custom post type.  Just amend your custom post type creation function to include the taxonomy, and so long as the name of the custom post type stays the same then everything will remain as it is.

The post data for your custom post type is all saved in the database (apart from files), and none of this is removed if you change the register function.

Comment: I have added taxonomy but it doesn't show the taxonomy in backend

Comment: How have you added the taxonomy?